# Prime React Tooltip not showing correct data

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, primereact

I want to show tooltip conditional by datatable attachment column data. If attachment is exist I'll show if not exist don't show tooltip.

I have a variable  `let [prList, setPrList] = useState([]);`

I am fetching this data by

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8081/view/all', {
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setPrList(data);
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    }, []);
```

And my datatable in return like

```
 <DataTable
                        value={prList}
                        paginator
                        filters={filters1}
                        emptyMessage="No record found."
                        showGridlines
                        filterDisplay="menu"
                        rows={10}
                        expandedRows={expandedRows}
                        onRowToggle={(e) => setExpandedRows(e.data)}
                        rowExpansionTemplate={rowExpansionTemplate}
                        onContextMenu={(e) => cm.current.show(e.originalEvent)}
                        contextMenuSelection={selectedPr}
                        onContextMenuSelectionChange={(e) => setSelectedPr(e.value)}
                        header={header}
                    >
                        <Column field="attachment" header="Attachment" dataType="boolean" bodyClassName="text-center" style={{ minWidth: '8rem' }} body={attachmentBodyTemplate} filter filterElement={attachmentFilterTemplate} sortable />
                    </DataTable>
```

With `body={attachmentBodyTemplate}` part I want to show like `Attachment Count: {rowData.prAttachDtoList.length}` But length is always 0. When I change mouse cursor to somewhere else and hover again it shows correct value for ex 2.

```
 const attachmentBodyTemplate = (rowData) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <i
                    className={classNames('pi', {
                        'text-green-500 pi-check-circle tooltip-button': rowData.attachment,
                        'text-pink-500 pi-times-circle': !rowData.attachment
                    })}
                    onClick={() => (rowData.attachment ? showAttachmentDialog('right', rowData) : undefined)}
                ></i>
                <Tooltip target=".tooltip-button" autoHide={false}>
                    <div className="flex align-items-center">
                        <span style={{ minWidth: '5rem' }}>Attachment Count: {rowData.prAttachDtoList.length}</span>
                    </div>
                </Tooltip>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: data-pr-tooltip="No notifications" adding to <i> fixed. Text inside tooltip buggy i guess

Answer (score 0):

That is because you must target an unique element, but you are targeting a class name.

I have done this on my projects:

```
const commentsBodyTemplate = (rowData: ServiceRequestInterface) => {
const nestedValue = _.get(rowData, "COMMENTS", "");
const targetValue = ".tooltip-button" + _.get(rowData, "_id", "");
const inputValue = "tooltip-button" + _.get(rowData, "_id", "");
return (
  <>
    <Tooltip target={targetValue} autoHide={false}>
      <div className="flex align-items-center">
        You tooltip here!
      </div>
    </Tooltip>
    <Button
      className={inputValue}
      icon="pi pi-info-circle"
      tooltipOptions={{ position: "left", showDelay: 1000, hideDelay: 3000 }}
    />
  </>
);};
```